# How to prove that $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \left(\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{|y|}\right) = 0$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, absolute-value

Prove that 
$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \left(\frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{1}{|y|}\right) = 0$$
I couldn't prove this. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE! We are not here to answer your homework problems. Please tell us what you find difficult or confusing.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you *could* prove it, because it's false!

Comment: As others have said, the statement you now present is false. So please elaborate.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 8):

Nobody can suggest a solution, because the statement is false.

If you approach $(0,0)$ with the sequence $(1/n,1/n)$ the limit is $\infty$. Therefore the given limit is certainly not $0$.

---

If your assignment was proving that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{|y|}\right)=0
$$
you need to show that, for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $M$ such that, for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>M$ (and $xy\ne0$) we have
$$
\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{|y|}<\varepsilon
$$
Now, for $a>0$ and $b>0$, we have
$$
\sqrt{ab}\le\frac{a+b}{2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{a+b}{ab}\le\frac{4}{a+b}\le\frac{8}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$
(the second inequality is readily verified). Thus, taking $M=8/\varepsilon$, for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>M$ we have
$$
\frac{8}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}<\frac{8}{M}=\varepsilon
$$
and we are done:
$$
\varepsilon=\frac{8}{M}>\frac{8}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\ge\frac{4}{|x|+|y|}\ge\frac{|x|+|y|}{|x|\,|y|}
=\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{1}{|y|}
$$

Comment: Maybe $\infty$ symbol looks like $oo=00=0$ :P

Comment: nice..............+1

Comment: The original post from OP wrote "as (x,y) tends to zero." @Shadock